# What version(s) of LISP have putprop?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I am hacking an old Lisp program, which once compiled and worked in Franz LISP, it is claimed. But Franz LISP is too old, so I am trying the CLISP compiler. However, CLISP does not have `putprop`.

I realise I could write a function that does the same thing as `putprop`, but in case I have to perform further translations, I am wondering: what version(s) of Lisp do have `putprop`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MACLISP had it.](http://maclisp.info/pitmanual/symbol.html#10.6.2)  Since [Franz Lisp is reportedly similar to MACLISP](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/01_ab.htm), there is a non-`zerop` chance that Kent Pitman's [Notes on Converting MACLISP/Zetalisp to Common Lisp](http://maclisp.info/pitmanual/cl-conv-01-intr.html) can help you in getting the code you're working with to run on a modern Common Lisp implementation.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent functionality is provided in Common Lisp by a combination of SETF and GET.

```
CL-USER 1 > (setf (get 'foo :bar) :baz)
:BAZ

CL-USER 2 > (get 'foo :bar)
:BAZ
```

Answer (score 0):

Portable Standard Lisp also has it, as does Interlisp. The reason Common Lisp doesn't is probably because of the execrable `SETF`, which you should not touch with a barge-pole, since it destructively modifies data structures. However, probably `putprop` in other legacy Lisps also work by destructive modification, so if you want to implement `putprop` you could do it:

```lisp
(defmacro putprop (var prop val)
  `(setf (get ,var ,prop) ,val))
```

Answer (score -1):

as I remember, Scheme has putprop; but do you call that a LISP?

---

ACL2, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACL2, also has putprop, and it's built on Common Lisp.

Comment: no, the LISP I meant is a little syntacticly different from Scheme. and I think a better solution for me is to use the LISP versions.

Comment: http://si.washington.edu/static/skandha4/manuals/slisp_289.html says XLISP has it; ok never mind, that's also a Scheme

Comment: see revised answer, I found a Common Lisp that has putprop. I don't believe I deserved a downvote in any case.

Comment: I wouldn't call XLISP "a scheme", even if XLISP1 had (IIRC) a single namespace for functions and variables. XLISP2 is, I believe, closer to Common Lisp.

Comment: The main statement of your answer is wrong, Scheme in general doesn't have putprop. It wouldn't even be possible to implement it, because Scheme symbols usually don't have property lists.

Comment: I remember it did when I played with it back in the early 90's. this webpage seems to agree: http://www.cs.indiana.edu/classes/b551-leak/scheme_practice.html

Comment: putprop/getprop were part of R2RS if I remember my old "Lisp Programming Language" book right.

Comment: also here, from 1987: http://books.google.com/books?ei=K0KmTdmTFoOH0QGGuajvCA&ct=result&id=GqhQAAAAMAAJ&dq=scheme+putprop&q=putprop#search_anchor